# Reconstructing an image from overlapping patches

Tags: image-processing, image

The Mathematica function [`ImagePartition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImagePartition.html) can create overlapping sub-images with the pixel offset options `{dw, dh}`:

```
ImagePartition[image, {w, h}, {dw, dh}]
```

Meanwhile, the [`ImageAssemble`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageAssemble.html) function has no such option documented.

Hence my question is: how would one reconstruct an image made up of overlapping patches?

- Is there an "easy" way?
- Or do I need to work through the list of
  patches one-by-one?

**Update:**

If I want each overlapping patch to contribute equally to the value of a single pixel in the final image, what would I do?

(Sorry, should have been clearer - have changed the title)

Comment: Welcome to our dedicated *Mathematica* site. If you like an answer, and you surely do because you accepted one, then you should definitely upvote the answer too. Currently, you cannot do this because you don't have enough reputation points, but once you get there, don't forget it.

Comment: Don't worry, I will do so!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this could be what you're looking for. First let's create a list of patches:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
patches = ImagePartition[img, 256, {128, 128}]
```

I'm not going to use `ImageAssemble` to put these back together. The trick is to create black and white masks, one for each patch. This is one example:

[image: Image mask]

And then to use `ImageMultiply` to create the following intermediate step:

[image: Intermediate step]

Now since black is `{0,0,0}` and each image has a the right dimensions we can add them all together using `ImageAdd`. The implementation looks like this:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
{w, h} = ImageDimensions[img];
masks[{w_, h_}, {partW_, partH_}, {offsetX_, offsetY_}] := 
  Flatten@Table[
    Graphics[{
      Black, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {w, h}],
      White, Rectangle[{offx, offy}, {offx + partW, offy + partH}]
      }, ImageSize -> {w, h}, 
     Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}], {offx, 0, 
     offsetX Floor[(w - partW)/offsetX], offsetX}, {offy, 0, 
     offsetY Floor[(h - partH)/offsetY], offsetY}
    ];
patchesCombine[patches_, masks_] := Module[{masked},
  masked = ImageMultiply[img, #] & /@ masks;
  Fold[ImageAdd, First@masked, Rest@masked]
  ]
```

And can be used like this:

```
patchesCombine[
 patches,
 masks[ImageDimensions[img], {256, 256}, {128, 128}]
 ]
```

[image: Result]

The arguments supplied to `masks` are the same arguments that you would supply to `ImagePartition`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
ip = ImagePartition[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], 40, {10, 10}] ;
ImageAssemble[Map[ImageCrop[#, {10, 10}] &, ip, {2}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What about if I want each of the overlapping patches to contribute equally to a pixel?

Comment: Unfortunately your result is smaller than the original image, so even without considering overlapping patches it's not really the inverse of the `ImagePartition` operation.

Comment: I've changed the question title!

Comment: (And sorry for making the question unclear at first @belisarius)

Comment: @blochwave No problem. I'll leave the answer anyway. Somebody may find it useful in the future for a slightly different problem